# Why am I unable to load a *.mat file in MATLAB 6.5.10?

Tags: matlab, mat, mat-file, matlab-load

When I load a mat file I've previously created in other system, i receive the following message:

```
Error using ==> load

Unable to read MAT file "..."

File may be corrupt.
```

Note: The dat file contains NaNs

Comment: MAT files do have [version info](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#inputarg_version) in them, it could be that the file you're trying to read is a newer version than that supported by 6.5.10.

Comment: If a newer version is not available, try octave or pymat to load and save in another version.

Comment: What version is the other system running? 6.5 is pretty antique, and 2 generations of `.mat` format behind current versions. Are you saving with the `-v6` option?